# python script directory location

Tags: python, directory

I have a question related to the directory of a python script or function. I give the following examples to show my question: suppose now we have a python file called `build_module.py`, which is located at:

```
C:/a/b/c/d/build_module.py
```

In this file I define a function called build_module:

```
def build_module(par1, par2)
    pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # first call
    print pwd_original
    os.chdir(pwd_original)
    print os.getcwd()
    pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #second call
    print pwd_original
    quit()
```

In this function when I first call `pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # first cal` I expect that the return path should be `C:/a/b/c/d`because this is the folder that the fie is located, however, what I got is `C:/a/b/c`. So this is my first question, why I can not obtain the file's folder? If `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` is not the right function that I should call, what kind of functions should I call?

After calling `os.chdir`, the second time `pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #second call`is called, the return path becomes 'C:/a/b', and what I expect is that it should be the same with the previous call. So, what happened?

**EDIT:**

Just to mention the way how I call the function. The script that I will use is located at

```
C:/a/b/c/d/app/main.py
```

Just to remind you that the build_module.py is located at `C:/a/b/c/d/build_module.py`. So if I want to call functions in build_module.py, I have to add `sys.path.insert(0,"../")` before import functions in this file.

If I put them in the same folder, then I will not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and did some corrections and ran it, and it printed three time the directory the script file is in. So the result is different to yours.

File is located in D:\PycharmProjects\PyDev and the output is

```
D:\PycharmProjects\PyDev
D:\PycharmProjects\PyDev
D:\PycharmProjects\PyDev
```

---

```
import os

def build_module(par1, par2):
   pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # first call
   print(pwd_original)
   os.chdir(pwd_original)
   print(os.getcwd())
   pwd_original = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #second call
   print (pwd_original)

build_module(1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But in my case the two files are not located in the same folder. As I said in the EDIT section, if they are put in the same folder, then no problem.